# Import a Python module into a Jinja template?

Tags: python, jinja2, python-import

Is it possible to import a Python module into a Jinja template so I can use its functions?

For example, I have a **format.py** file that contains methods for formatting dates and times. In a Jinja macro, can I do something *like* the following?

```
{% from 'dates/format.py' import timesince %}

{% macro time(mytime) %}
<a title="{{ mytime }}">{{ timesince(mytime) }}</a>
{% endmacro %}
```

Because **format.py** is not a template, the code above gives me this error:

```
UndefinedError: the template 'dates/format.py' (imported on line 2 in 'dates/macros.html') does not export the requested name 'timesince'
```

...but I was wondering if there was another way to achieve this.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Within the template, no, you cannot import python code.

The way to do this is to register the function as a jinja2 [custom filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#custom-filters), like this:

In your python file:

```
from dates.format import timesince

environment = jinja2.Environment(whatever)
environment.filters['timesince'] = timesince
# render template here
```

In your template:

```
{% macro time(mytime) %}
<a title="{{ mytime }}">{{ mytime|timesince }}</a>
{% endmacro %}
```

Comment: I found this link helpful if Jinja Filters are confusing you: https://ttl255.com/jinja2-tutorial-part-4-template-filters/

Answer (score 44):

Just pass the function into the template, like so

```
from dates.format import timesince
your_template.render(timesince)
```

and in the template, just call it like any other function,

```
{% macro time(mytime) %}
    <a title="{{ mytime }}">{{ timesince(mytime) }}</a>
{% endmacro %}
```

Functions are first-class citizens in python, so you can pass them around just like anything else. You could even pass in a whole module if you wanted.

Answer (score 21):

A template doesn't know [`import`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/simple_stmts.html#import), but you can teach it with the [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/importlib.html):

```
import importlib
my_template.render( imp0rt = importlib.import_module )  # can't use 'import', because it's reserved
```

(you can also name it `"import"` by passing the argument with a `dict`)

```
kwargs = { 'import' : importlib.import_module }
my_template.render( **kwargs )
```

then in the jinja-template, you can import any module:

```
{% set time = imp0rt( 'time' ) %}
{{ time.time() }}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can export all of the symbols available in a module by providing the modules __dict__ as a parameter to the jinja template render method. The following will make available functions and types of __builtin__, inspect and types module to the template.

```
import __builtin__
import inspect
import types

env=RelEnvironment()
template = env.get_template(templatefile)

export_dict={}
export_dict.update(__builtin__.__dict__)
export_dict.update(types.__dict__)
export_dict.update(inspect.__dict__)

result=template.render(**export_dict)
```

Within template, to use a function of the exported modules similar to the following:

```
{%- for element in getmembers(object) -%}
{# Use the getmembers function from inspect module on an object #}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass module to `render` function like this:

```
from src.constants import proto

wls = {"workloads": [{"name": "test1", "p": "UDP"}, {"name": "test2", "p": "TCP_NONTLS"}]}

env = Environment(
        loader=PackageLoader("src", "templates")
    )
template = env.get_template("lds.yaml.j2")
print(template.render(wls,proto=proto))
```

In jinja template you can now use `proto`:

```
{% if workload.p == proto.udp -%}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Flask, you can add imports to the Jinja context using a [Flask context processor](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/templating/#context-processors). For example, here's how you can make the modules `datetime`, `email.utils`, and `os.path` available in all templates:

```py
app = Flask(__name__)

import email.utils, datetime, os.path
@app.context_processor
def add_imports():
    # Note: we only define the top-level module names!
    return dict(email=email, datetime=datetime, os=os)
```