# Flask - How to properly set global values

Tags: python, flask, global-variables

I'm currently working on a web app where I'm using Flask and the Flask-User extension to handle authorization. At the moment I have something like this:

```
@application.route('/dummy')
@roles_required('Admin')
@login_required
def dummy():
```

in my `views.py` file and something like this:

```
{% if current_user.is_authenticated and current_user.has_roles('Admin') %}
```

in my templates.

Now, there's been a few times where I've changed my mind in terms of role names and then had to search through the whole project to find and replace those usages. I wanted to define something like a `ADMIN_ROLE` global that can be accessed inside my `views.py` or any templates. I'd then just change a config file whenever I wanted to change a role's name.

I tried using my `config.py` setting `ADMIN_ROLE = "Admin"` and writing `@roles_required(current_app.config['ADMIN_ROLE'])` but that gives me the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
to interface with the current application object in a way.  To solve
this set up an application context with app.app_context().  See the
documentation for more information.
```

so that should be wrong. What would be the most correct way to accomplish what I'm trying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it says, you can only access config from within the app context. Normally, you do this:

```
with current_app.app_context():
    admin_role = current_app.config['ADMIN_ROLE']
```

Because you're doing this in a decorator, I don't believe there's anyway to do that. I would suggest just using a separate module. Now, it [doesn't appear](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4829057/5854907) that you can use python `import` statements in jinja, so we'll still use `app.config` for that. Basically we'll create a module with the desired roles and then import that into the config file and your routes file.

roles.py

```
ADMIN = "Admin"
USER = "User"
```

config.py

```
from roles import ADMIN, USER

ADMIN_ROLE = ADMIN
USER_ROLE = USER
```

routes.py

```
from roles import ADMIN, USER

@application.route('/dummy')
@roles_required(ADMIN)
@login_required
def dummy():
```

views.py

```
{% if current_user.is_authenticated and current_user.has_roles(app.config['ADMIN_ROLE']) %}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a great answer.
This seems to be the most logical path to follow and looks like a clean solution, despite we still having to use `app.config` in jinja. Do you agree that what I'm trying to accomplish is better than just writing the string name of the role everywhere?

Comment: Yes, if there is something in code that may change, it's better to change it in one place than several.

Comment: I've ran into a small issue. When using javascript with Jinja, I do something like this: `if($(this).val() !== {{ config['ADMIN_ROLE'] }})` which is translated to `if($(this).val() !== Admin)`, where ADMIN is the name of the variable imported in config.py and not it's value of `"Admin"`

Comment: You need it to be a string literal in JavaScript. Add quotes around the brackets. `"{{ config['ADMIN_ROLE'] }}"` May be typos as I made this comment on my phone.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: Though I would encourage you to not embed JavaScript into html. If you need to pass data to JavaScript, I would suggest assigning it to the value of a `input` element with `type="hidden"`. Then access it by the element's id.