# How to open a file and get content from a jinja template

Tags: python, jinja2

I want a put a random line from a file using jinja template.

for ex:
I have a list of names (1000+) stored in a file. I want to pick a random name from that file and put it in template.

something like below:

```
Name={{ import_file_as_list("name_samples.txt") | random }}
```

Is it possible? How can we achieve so using jinja without changing the rendering logic?

Note: I can **not** modified the rendering logic (python file), as I am using a rest api to render.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828406/import-a-python-module-into-a-jinja-template, then import the random module and use random.choice()

Comment: @JayJoshi you can't if you use only api.