# Iterate over json string items in jinja2

Tags: python, templates, jinja2

Hi I need to send data in string format to my jinja templates, and the render them. The only way I found is to format my data as JSON and send it as a string to the renderer. But I don´t know how to use it in the templates, it seems that the `tojson` filter it´s not for this purpose, because it keeps rendered a string.

to keep it simple I'm doing something similar to:

```
import json

a = {"a":1,"b":[1,2,3,4]}
response = json.dumps(a)
```

in template:

```
{{ response }}
{{ response|tojson }}
```

both give a string response, not a dict or an object that I can use to render based on the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import json to use it's load function to load it into jinja.

```py
from json import loads

environment = jinja2.Environment(whatever)
environment.filters['load'] = loads
```

```html
{{ response|load }}
```

Reference:
[Import a Python module into a Jinja template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828406/import-a-python-module-into-a-jinja-template)

Comment: thank !, I edit your answer because in this case is `loads` instead of load